# Google Sheets Conditional formatting does not support Defined Name ranges

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

My conditional format formula is:

```
=indirect(cell(Laddress,index(InitGrid,row(D4)-RorgRC,column(D4)-CorgRC)))
```

This formula works fine in a spreadsheet cell - i.e. all addressing works.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Question still stands, but I found a much simpler formula that works: =indirect("Sheet!RC",false)

Answer (score 1):

in Google Sheets' Conditional formatting (and Data Validation) all references to another sheet (even named ranges) need to be wrapped into **`INDIRECT`** formula.